# How to print docx and pdf?

Tags: java, python

I actually can print using the txt file to printer, however, when I change to docx or pdf I get  many undefined characters which cannot be understood at all. Do you guys have any ideas on how to solve this.

The code I used.

```
import system
import javax.print
import java.io
from java.lang import Thread

filestream = java.io.BufferedInputStream(java.io.FileInputStream("C:/GEEKS.txt"))

psInformat = javax.print.DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE

myDoc = javax.print.SimpleDoc(filestream,psInformat,None)

aset = javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet()
aset.add(javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies(2))

services = javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService()

job = services.createPrintJob()

job.print(myDoc, None)

Thread.sleep(20000)

filestream.close()
```

Comment: when i mean change,it mean i try GEEK.docx or GEEK.pdf

Answer (score 0):

.docx files have far more formatting and nonsense going on than a text file. Open one up using notepad and you'll see exactly what I'm talking about.

Because of this, you'll need to use a dedicated library to read the docx file, such as
`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx/0.2.4`

This library even provides a nice way to extract the text from a docx file:

`example-extracttext.py 'Some word file.docx' 'new file.txt'`

Comment: Hi Noah,does that mean i need to convert the txt to docx in this script?Thanks.